# What is the purpose of %ORACLE_HOME%/dbs directory in Windows Environment?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I see some files in there like an `init.ora` and `opctrn11.h`, but what is the purpose of this directory, if we use `%ORACLE_HOME%/database` to store the p/spfile instead?

Answer (score 1):

$ORACLE_HOME/dbs is used to store the spfiles, init files and password files on Linux and Unix systems. But as you pointed out the dbs directory not used on windows servers. So on a Windows servers it is probably not needed.

Comment: It is something that is created by the Oracle install though and as such I wouldn't delete it.

Comment: Right don't delete it, but it isn't really useful.